# How to improve question to avoid downvotes

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes

I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593437/google-analytics-report-results-depends-on-query) and it was down voted without any comment. I have no idea how to improve it. I feel there is no need for any images (also the data is private). If somebody could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: Your question asks why you get different results for different queries but doesn't include the actual queries or example data.

Comment: You don't need to use the real, private data. Instead, set up an example set of data that shows the same issue without compromising real world data. While you're setting up the example, you may even find the answer yourself. If you don't, this at least allows other users to reproduce your scenario. Of course, you need to add the actual queries (that fit the example data) as well.

Comment: OK, I looked at the question.   It has none of the important details that would assist debugging, eg. the two outputs and the set that is common and not common.  Also, the ranges overlap by one day.  I have to down and close vote:(

Comment: foo your data. give us SOME sort of context.. also, be careful linking a question that has been deemed as 'bad' by other users. You're almost opening yourself up to downvotes. Just a heads up.

Comment: @JasonVanBenschoten I was going to tell him that too... and then I was hoping that someone coming here for support would be given the benefit of assistance before suffering the wrath of downvotes.

Comment: @JasonVanBenschoten unfortunately, looking at the -6 votes and the closed mark of death on it, I see that was too much to ask for. Anton, if you edit your question to address what we have brought up, it will go back to the Reopen queue and you will be able to get some help.

Comment: OP got an hour, and did not respond with any useful information.  That, and failing to double-check the date ranges to be sure that they were equivalent, got a downvote, and I don't feel even slightly guilty about it.

Comment: @martinjames No, I guess you shouldn't. It's just a shame he brought down the meta effect on his head unwittingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to post the actual data, just a representative sample. For example, if you're using Social Security Numbers as an ID, you don't need to post all 20,000 of them, just post two rows with numbers like `111-11-1111` and `222-22-2222`. And you also only really need to show examples of relevant fields you are working with. We don't need everything.

Also, you really need to post the query. No one can help you debug something you haven't given them.